# How to solve current flowing through a component in a A/C circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

In that given equation j(t)=5sin(ωt)A , where ω=2πf and f=50Hz
R=50ohms and C=100μF

In polar form I=5/sqrt(2)//0° , where //0° indicates the phase angle

Task is to solve the current ic(t).

I tried to compute a source exchange, where the new voltage source is e=E=RJ and J is
j(t) but in polar form and the original resistor R is now in series with E.
50*5/sqrt(2)//0° = 250/sqrt(2)//0°

After that it should be easy to compute the total impedance by just adding Zr and Zc together.

I got Zr=50+j0, obviously, then Zc=0-j31.83 in rectangle form.
total impedance is given by Zr+Zc=(50+j0)(0-j31.83)=50-j31.83 , which you can convert into polar form = Ztot = 59.27//-32.48°

Current flowing through the circuit is given by I=E/Ztot
(250/sqrt(2)//0°)/(59.27//-32.48°) = 2.98//-32.48°

So my question here is, that am I completely off with my solution? Or if I am indeed correct, then is there a more efficient way of coming up with the solution? I don't want answers to my problem, just advice.

Comment: Notice that the resistor and the capacitor are not connected in series but are connected in parallel. Therefore Ztot is not equal R + Xc because we do not have a series connection.

Comment: @G36 You overlooked the "source exchange" part.  The resistor was folded with the current source to result in a voltage source in _series_ with the same _resistance_.  That's valid for calculating the current through the _capacitor_, but not so for calculating the current through the _resistor_.

Comment: @periblepsis You overlooked the "source exchange" part.  That's actually what JonnyB did.  I contest that this is easier than the answer I gave.

Answer (score 1):

One can calculate this using admittances rather than resistances since in a parallel circuit the admittances just add, and the resulting voltage is the total current divided by the total admittance.  From the total (complex) voltage you can then easily calculate the (same phase-angle) current through the resistor, and the current through the capacitor is then what remains from the total current of the current source.

EDIT: the original version stated the resulting voltage to be the total current *multiplied* by the total admittance which is wrong.  With the correction, the math is just the same as with the proposed solutions (you don't get around a complex division/inversion).

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the current divider formula, we can see that:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_\text{C}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\cdot\underline{\text{I}}_\text{i}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{RC}\omega\text{j}}{\displaystyle1+\text{RC}\omega\text{j}}\cdot\underline{\text{I}}_\text{i}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_\text{C}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\text{RC}\omega}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\text{RC}\omega\right)^2}}\cdot\left|\underline{\text{I}}_\text{i}\right|\tag2$$
$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_\text{C}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\text{RC}\omega\right)+\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_\text{i}\right)\tag3$$

So, when the input current has no phase difference with the sine function, we get:

$$\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle5\text{RC}\omega}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\text{RC}\omega\right)^2}}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\text{RC}\omega\right)\right)\tag4$$

Answer (score 0):

> Task is to solve the current ic(t).
>
> ... is there a more efficient way of coming up with the solution? I don't
> want answers to my problem, just advice.

The current in the capacitor is, I think, more easily/directly found when you did this conversion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmBc4g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The loop current computed this way solves the capacitor current question, readily.

Here's the result I get from my calculator:

```
f
Freq or omega (add 'j'): 50
250/(50+100uF)
3.5579978 + j2.26509175, 4.21781804 < 32.4816366
```

The RMS value would be 2.98244774 and I think this confirms your approach. I doubt there's an easier approach. There may be other approaches. But I think that's truly the simplest in getting exactly at the result desired.

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP did.

Comment: @user107063 I just added a note.